# SSE optimization of Gaussian blur

Tags: c++, optimization, sse, simd, gaussianblur

I'm working on a school project , I have to optimize part of code in SSE, but I'm stuck on one part for few days now.

I dont see any smart way of using vector SSE instructions(inline assembler / instric f) in this code(its a part of guassian blur algorithm). I would be glad if somebody could give me just a small hint

```
for (int x = x_start; x < x_end; ++x)     // vertical blur...
    {
        float sum = image[x + (y_start - radius - 1)*image_w];
        float dif = -sum;

        for (int y = y_start - 2*radius - 1; y < y_end; ++y)
        {                                                   // inner vertical Radius loop           
            float p = (float)image[x + (y + radius)*image_w];   // next pixel
            buffer[y + radius] = p;                         // buffer pixel
            sum += dif + fRadius*p;
            dif += p;                                       // accumulate pixel blur

            if (y >= y_start)
            {
                float s = 0, w = 0;                         // border blur correction
                sum -= buffer[y - radius - 1]*fRadius;      // addition for fraction blur
                dif += buffer[y - radius] - 2*buffer[y];    // sum up differences: +1, -2, +1

                // cut off accumulated blur area of pixel beyond the border
                // assume: added pixel values beyond border = value at border
                p = (float)(radius - y);                   // top part to cut off
                if (p > 0)
                {
                    p = p*(p-1)/2 + fRadius*p;
                    s += buffer[0]*p;
                    w += p;
                }
                p = (float)(y + radius - image_h + 1);               // bottom part to cut off
                if (p > 0)
                {
                    p = p*(p-1)/2 + fRadius*p;
                    s += buffer[image_h - 1]*p;
                    w += p;
                }
                new_image[x + y*image_w] = (unsigned char)((sum - s)/(weight - w)); // set blurred pixel
            }
            else if (y + radius >= y_start)
            {
                dif -= 2*buffer[y];
            }
        } // for y
    } // for x
```

Comment: You learn about SSE at school? That's pretty cool.

Comment: yeah :), its a voluntary subject about advanced assemblers, but deadline is approaching and im stuck on this for really long time :/

Comment: Unfortunately I think you're going to have to completely re-implement this if you want to use SSE. You should pre-compute a 1D kernel of coefficients and then use SSE to perform convolution in each axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One more feature you can use is logical operations and masks:

for example instead of:

```
  // process only 1
if (p > 0)
    p = p*(p-1)/2 + fRadius*p;
```

you can write

```
  // processes 4 floats
const __m128 &mask = _mm_cmplt_ps(p,0);
const __m128 &notMask = _mm_cmplt_ps(0,p);
const __m128 &p_tmp = ( p*(p-1)/2 + fRadius*p );
p = _mm_add_ps(_mm_and_ps(p_tmp, mask), _mm_and_ps(p, notMask)); // = p_tmp & mask + p & !mask
```

2. Also I can recommend you to use a special libraries, which overloads instructions. For example: http://code.compeng.uni-frankfurt.de/projects/vc
3. `dif` variable makes iterations of inner loop dependent. You should try to parallelize the outer loop. But with out instructions overloading the code will become unmanageable then.
4. Also consider rethinking the whole algorithm. Current one doesn't look paralell. May be you can neglect precision, or increase scalar time a bit?

Comment: i hope i understand u correctly mate, i already tried that and it works but problem is in statements like  sum += dif + fRadius*p; , where i need to use dif from previous cycle, which i cant obtain when im trying to compute 4 cycles at once

Comment: @user2174310, I see. You should try to parallelize the outer loop. But with out instructions overloads the code will become unmanageable then.

Comment: 4.7x (approx) faster, with outer loop parallelization, thanks for advice guys